# Calling Fragment from RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

I have a recyclerView that shows a list in cardView. This recyclerview is located in one fragment that shown in a viewPager tab. I want to go to new Fragment when thumbnail in cardview is clicked.

I implemented following `onBindViewHolder` in order to have this functionality:

```html
holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    Fragment productDetailFragment = new ProductDetailFragment();
    (FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.grid_page_recycler_view, productDetailFragment).commit();
                }
            });
```

But after running, it returns:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findMinMaxChildLayoutPositions(RecyclerView.java:3757)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3494)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3019)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15819)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15819)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1658)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15819)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15819)
                  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15819)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4890)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15819)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4890)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15819)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4890)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15819)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1965)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1146)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1356)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1046)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4603)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What's the reason? It's notable that if I want to call another activity, it is easy to implement.

Thanks.

And I must say that there are several similar questions here, but I could not use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create one method for replacing fragment in your MAinActivity.
- Take ViewPager in a Fragment and push it from MainActivity.
- Now Call replace fragment method in your recyclerView Adapter.

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

    if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName) == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, backStateName);
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i call that method

Comment: you can call it by doing ((MainActivity)context).replaceFragment(fragment);